# Different ways/approaches to how to send notification to every subscriber in a server/client tcp implementation

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, publish-subscribe

I want to show what I've thought so far, and say that right now I have a client (subscriber) that does connect and sends messages to the server (intermediary between subscribers and editors).

I have a list where I store every topic that a subscriber can subscribe to, and a list of the subscribers for each node of that list.

As of right now subscribers can register or drop out from a topic. My issue is now to notify to every subscriber of a topic when does a editor generate an event.

To do this I thought of, well, I go through the list of the topic of the event, and send a message to each subscriber of said topic, subscriber gets it, he's been notified.

But to do this only way I can think of right now would be to have something like this code:

```
int sock_tcp; 
struct sockaddr_in  dir_tcp_srv;  
sock_tcp=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(sock_tcp<0)
{
  fprintf(stdout,"ERROR\n");
  exit(1);
}

bzero((char*)&dir_tcp_srv,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 
dir_tcp_srv.sin_family=AF_INET;
dir_tcp_srv.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(address_previously_stored);
dir_tcp_srv.sin_port=htons(port_previously_stored);
if(connect(sock_tcp,                
     (struct sockaddr*)&dir_tcp_srv,
     sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0)
{

  perror("CONNECT error");
  close(sock_tcp); exit(1);
}
```

Where I put that on a function for example (this is the code I currently use to connect subscribers to intermediary process), and give it two paramters like address and port, and just go through the list, calling this code each time just with different parameters.

This seems a bit dumb to me and like I'm missing some kind of point or concept, in the sense that I'm using the same code all of the time and it seems a bit of a waste. I believe with a different implementation I could do some kind of broadcast and the subscriber would just get the info but it's a "push" subscriber-editor mode so I believe my idea is the one that fits that concept (instead of doing a pull from the subscriber whenever he wants the info and so on).

Comment: If you understand C++, please go through the observer design pattern. You will get the complete picture how to implement the above behavior.

Comment: I can't say I am. I'm writing in C and I beleive they hold similarities and all that but that's about it. I remember I had read this at some point maybe when I started thinking about how to implement the issue 

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FObserver_pattern&ei=OMcmVcCvN4yzUe6ngqAF&usg=AFQjCNGRWwxlv75N0vj4Ifwc0q4NnXIbrg&sig2=Fx7YVGDE-gFxeyE2VDj7Jw&bvm=bv.90491159,d.d24

But it's not exactly helping. Any source you know that explains it?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the networking side of the problem and C++ is not a tag.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a peer to peer protocol that has 2 ends and is connection oriented.
If you stick to TCP as communication mechanism for this, you will have to iterate though all your subscribers setup a connection, send and close because TCP is not multicast.

If you were to use UDP then you could broadcast this easily but even then you are confined in the boundaries of your subnet.

Comment: Allright so I was somehow with the right approach in mind then it seems?

I have done mixed udp-tcp "writes" and "reads" in the past, I will have to look whether this would be useful now, not quite sure how to do it since the subscriber is kind of specific as to what it has to do.